# Do JOOQ-generated classes have any dependency on licensed JOOQ jars(ex. enterprise edition - trial version)?

Tags: entity, enterprise, jooq, trial, generated-code

I mean once the trial expires, what is the impact to the codes using jooq for persistence and its generated entity classes?

Answer (score 0):

There are two somewhat different questions here:

> Do JOOQ-generated classes have any dependency on licensed JOOQ jars?

Yes, the classes depend on the jOOQ runtime binaries. For instance, a generated table `Book` might look as follows:

```java
public class Book extends TableImpl<BookRecord> {
    //       ^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^
    //         |              |         |
    // Your class             |         |
    //                        |         |
    // Classes from the jOOQ binaries --+
    // ...
}
```

For technical details, see also: http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-tables/

> Once the trial expires, what is the impact to the codes using jooq for persistence and its generated entity classes?

You can keep the generated entity classes, they're yours (even if generated with the free trial), e.g. for documentation purposes. But they're not really useful without the runtime binaries, as you won't be able to use them, without removing the dependency.

<sup>**Disclaimer**: Some might consider Stack Overflow as not an adequate place to ask legal questions in general. I'm giving this informal answer as I work for the company behind jOOQ. This answer is useful for understanding jOOQ 3.x commercial licensing, but does not constitute a part of any formal agreement.</sup>

Comment: Hi Lukas. Thank you for a quick response. I'm new to jooq and we're trying to know what the license is all about and the impact once it expires.
For example, I added the jooq 3.7.2 enterprise edition jars to my project to be able to use their libraries and we are going to use it instead of hibernate.

How does 30-day trial period start? when I start generating classes, querying and persisting to DB?

My manager needs to know the effect of this expiration in terms of usage. Once it expires, will I still be able to use CRUD etc? 

I read the FAQ on licensing but I could not understand fully yet.

Comment: *"How does 30-day trial period start?"* - When you click "accept" on your download. *"Once it expires, will I still be able to use CRUD etc?"* - No, you must delete the jOOQ trial edition binaries from your system after trial expiration. Also, it will stop working after some time. Please, do get in touch with sales@datageekery.com if you have further questions, we'll be very happy to help.

Comment: It does make sense now. Thank you Lukas!!